# Selecting custom output cache provider for specific controller actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to implement a MongoDB / Memory combined Output Cache Provider to use with MVC4. Here is my initial implementation:

```
public class CustomOutputCacheProvider : OutputCacheProvider
{
    public override object Get(string key)
    {
        FileLogger.Log(key);
        return null;
    }

    public override object Add(string key, object entry, DateTime utcExpiry)
    {
        return entry;
    }

    public override void Set(string key, object entry, DateTime utcExpiry)
    {
    }

    public override void Remove(string key)
    {
    }
}
```

And my web config entry:

```
<caching>
  <outputCache defaultProvider="CustomOutputCacheProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="CustomOutputCacheProvider" type="MyApp.Base.Mvc.CustomOutputCacheProvider" />
    </providers>
  </outputCache>
</caching>
```

And the usage within HomeController:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 15)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return Content("Home Page");
}
```

My problem is, when I check the logfile for the keys that are requested, I see not only the request to home controller, but all other paths as well:

```
a2/  <-- should only log this entry
a2/test
a2/images/test/50115c53/1f37e409/4c7ab27d/50115c531f37e4094c7ab27d.jpg
a2/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js
```

I've figured that I shouldn't set the CustomOutputCacheProvider as the defaultProvider in Web.Config, what I couldn't figure out is how to specify the cache provider that I want to use for a specific controller action.

With Asp.Net Web Pages you can accomplish it by using `<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="None" providerName="DiskCache" %>` at the top of the page, but for MVC the only solution I could find is to override [HttpApplication.GetOutputCacheProviderName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.getoutputcacheprovidername.aspx) in Global.asax.

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this by using the [OutputCache] attribute?

Comment: Out of interest what is `a2/test` and how does it fit in with the original request `a2/`?

Comment: No idea really, what I request is `http://host/test`. Mvc adds the a2 (see [OutputCacheAttribute.cs](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/98d041ae352f#src%2fSystem.Web.Mvc%2fOutputCacheAttribute.cs) ) while generating the key

Comment: You might want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/43405118/51734

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a more elegant way to set the OutputCacheProvider using the [OutputCache] attribute?

I think the answer is no, (well not with the current mvc4 release) since there is no relationship between implementing a custom `OutputCacheProvider` and decorating an action with the `OutputCache` attribute.

As you discovered by implementing the custom provider and *logging* in the Get method you see every request made to the web server. If you were to remove the `OutputCache` attribute from all your actions you will still see every request in out log file. I thought the answer for this [ASP.NET MVC hits outputcache for every action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10175565/81053) was pretty useful to confirm that.

Since it looks like you only want to implement one output-cache provider then I think your only option is to *not* set the default provider and continue to override the `GetOutputCacheProviderName` implementation (as you have already mentioned). Perhaps something like this to exclude all *Content*, *Images* and *Scripts*

```
public override string GetOutputCacheProviderName(HttpContext context)
{
    string absolutePath = context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

    if (absolutePath.StartsWith("/Content/", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
        || absolutePath.StartsWith("/Scripts/", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
        || absolutePath.StartsWith("/Images/", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        return base.GetOutputCacheProviderName(context);

    return "CustomOutputCacheProvider";
}
```

If you need to implement more than one output-cache provider then I guess you'll have to implement a helper to give you the correct provider name. But here's an example where I've resolved the routing data for you; where as the prev example looked directly at the url.

```
public override string GetOutputCacheProviderName(HttpContext context)
{       
    RouteCollection rc = new RouteCollection();
    MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(rc);
    RouteData rd = rc.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));

    if (rd == null)
        return base.GetOutputCacheProviderName(context);

    var controller = rd.Values["controller"].ToString();
    var action = rd.Values["action"].ToString();

    if (controller.Equals("Content", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
        || controller.Equals("Scripts", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
        || controller.Equals("Images", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        return base.GetOutputCacheProviderName(context);

    if (controller.Equals("Account", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        return "AccountOutputCacheProvider";
    if (controller.Equals("Something", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        return controller + "OutputCacheProvider";

    return "CustomOutputCacheProvider";
}
```

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but the link helped. Looks like I'm gonna have to implement my own solution.

Answer (score 1):

If i where you, i would try to write MyOutputCachAttribute inherited from OutputCachAttribute that will choose provider by its parameter.

Comment: I've considered it, but it seems like almost equal job to implement my own caching mechanism. See [OutputCacheAttribute.cs](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/98d041ae352f#src%2fSystem.Web.Mvc%2fOutputCacheAttribute.cs)

Answer (score 0):

Check this article from MSDN Magazine (with source code and examples referencing MongoDB & Azure as distributed cache providers) may well provide some insight http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650661.aspx

**EDIT**

Can you use the CacheProfile setting to specify the provider as suggested here?

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=665

Comment: Unfortunately, the CacheProfile doesn't have the set provider setting.